# echoing the result of find to BufferedReader in Java

Tags: java, bash

I am trying to get an input stream from a runtime execution. But the following code doesn't give me anything in the getInputStream() . I am trying to get the number of files in a parent directory "DPATH" and the files under its sub directories. The code below gives me an empty input stream . I'd like to have a number like i do when use the command in bash `"find /mypath -type f | wc -l "`

```
String line = "";
String command = "find /DPATH -type f | wc -l"
Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( pr.getInputStream()));

while( ( line = buff.readLine() ) != null  && !isCancelled() )
   {
      count = Integer.parseInt(line);
   }

 if (!isCancelled())
    {
      pr.waitFor();
      buff.close();
      pr.destroy();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `find` when the Java library already contains simple functionality that does not require the complexity and unreliability of launching an external process?  Take a look at the `java.nio.file.Files` class. It provides everything you need without having to invoke any external process. Look at `Files#walk(...)` and `Files#walkFileTree(...)`.   Writing a `wc` equivalent is only a few lines of code.

Comment: Or just check out the java.io.File class.  It has a method named list() that returns an array of type File.  You can determine from that how many file items there are while filtering out directories.

Comment: @JimGarrison  because i need to know how to retrieve the inputstream. I'll look at your suggested solution, but it would be really helpful if i can realize the above.

Comment: Does the path `/DPATH` actually exist?  Have you stepped through this code in your IDE debugger to make sure the process actually got launched and didn't fail?  Is `find` on the path given to subprocesses? Do you need to specify the full path to the `find` command?

Comment: @JimGarrison , ok, so i was looking at the Files.walk() and files.copy. I am interested in using the copy of the nio api ,  but is there anyway to capture the number of files copied as they are being copied. This is why i was i trying to use the number of files in a directory, so i can get the number of files as i'm copying using `sed` command in order to show the progress bar copying process. So i need numbers , the total size and the ones being copied to have a quotient.

Comment: Do it in your `FileVisitor` (which you write).